# Wordpress always view first page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm creating a custom wordpress theme (index.php header and footer). I need 2 pages: home page and products. My home page is in `header` and `footer.css.`

When I make one page in `wp-admin` and open it, I always see my default page coded in header and footer.php. However I did not change the `.htaccess` file!

When I type any other url, wordpress always shows me the default page.

How can I have **2 different** pages in a custom wordpress theme?
Both pages must have different css.

Comment: I am not really clear from your questions, if you have template type created, when you creating page from wp-admin assign it to correct template type.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Page Template as: page-product.php and add code follow

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Template Name: Page Product
 * This is the template that displays product.
 *
 */

get_header('product'); ?>
//Loop query here
<?php get_footer(product); ?>
```

Now, when you create a Page you can select a Templage `Page Product` for Product width `header/footer` diferent with `header/footer` of Homepage

[View Image Select Page Template Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5Vln.jpg)

[Follow document Page Template here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)

Comment: thans for help.But i still have same problem.Ok lets me explain.I crate 2 new file in my project foler(page-product.php and product.php) and paste your code.Now i crate one page with template Page Product and i get this url http://localhost/xyz/pageproduct/ ‎ and when i load that i see my default page always...

Comment: all file you can create in your template: `header-product.php` (different header default ) & `footer-product.php` (if you want)  and `page-product.php` (width my code). Now you create a page as: `Test Product` and select template Page Product. => You can view: localhost/xyz/test-product see different header / footer / loop query. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you can make one of 2 things

or to create a template page - like the last answer

you put php comment at the start of page :

`/*Template Name: ________[ what ever you would like ] */`

and call the page as your call the template name

in this page - you have to put - the loop

and inside the loop - put : `the_content();` function

now - go to dashboard - in the current page - choose the template you create 
and not the default page - and save it

or to create a page - for the current page using his id or his slag

you can find id or slag in the url of the page `[ post=__ ]`

for example : `page-shop.php`

in this page - you have to put - the loop

and inside the loop - put : `the_content();` function

and you will have other page